# Angular esbuild ckeditor. No loader is configured for ".svg"

Tags: angular, ckeditor5, esbuild

I use [ckEditor](https://ckeditor.com/). If I import a ckEditor plugin, I get this error

`No loader is configured for ".svg" files: node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/table.svg`

My versions:

```
Angular version: 17.1.2
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular: 7.0.1
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic: 41.0.0
```

```js
import { Autoformat } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat'
export const CK_EDITOR_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
   plugins: [
     // Essentials,
     // UploadAdapter,
     Autoformat,
   ]
}
```

Does Angular with esbuild support a custom loader? Or are there any other solutions to support svg loader?

I added `d.ts` to src, but it doesn't help:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
   const content: string
   export default content
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Simplifying File Imports in Angular with New Loader Options](https://netbasal.com/simplifying-file-imports-in-angular-with-new-loader-options-4e94a0eb18af)

In angular.json from version 17.1.0, we can add loaders in config:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "options": {
        ...
        "loader": {
          ".svg": "text"
        },
```

Comment: Nice find @Andrey Lebedev :) If this solved your issue don't forget to accept it as the answer ✅