Getting "No loader is configured for ".svg" files" while adding custom plugins in ckeditor5
I am using @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic in my Rails 7 application without webpack configuration.
the Classic Editor is working fine, but when I use the plugins (like: @ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing), then I am getting the below error when I build or run the application,
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".svg" files
Below is my package.json file
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^41.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^41.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing": "^41.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "css-loader": "5",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.47",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "postcss-loader": "4",
    "raw-loader": "4",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "stimulus-autocomplete": "^3.0.2",
    "style-loader": "2",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
}


I have tried lots of different configurations, but nothing works. Every article says to use webpack, but I don't want to add it in my application, and the @ckeditor/ckeditor5 docs does not have any support for the Rails application.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77930365/angular-esbuild-ckeditor-no-loader-is-configured-for-svg
